# If $A=\frac{D}{BC}$, with $B$, $C$, $D$ to at most two decimal places, then to how many places do I round $A$ so that $ABC$ returns $D$ to two places?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, significant-figures

I have an equation
$$\frac{D}{BC} = A$$

- $B$ is any positive number (inclusive) between $0.01$ and $999.99$ (never more than $2$ decimal places)
- $C$ is any positive number (inclusive) between $1.00$ and $2.00$ (never more than $2$ decimal places)
- $D$ is any positive number (inclusive) between $0.01$ and $999,999.99$ (never more than $2$ decimal places)

For all possible values $B$, $C$, and $D$, what is the smallest number of decimal places that I can round $A$ to such that when I re-multiply it by $B$ and $C$, and round the product to two digits, it always equals the original $D$. (How do I find that?)

Comment: The most off any value B,C,D can be off by is $0.005$.  Compare the difference between $d=D-0.005$ and $c=C+0.005; d=D+0.005$ and compare that to $d'=D+0.005; c'=C-0.005;b'=B-0.005$ and see how $a = \frac d{bc}; A=\frac D{BC}; a'=\frac {d'}{b'c'}$ compare.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that answers my question. Or if it does answer my question, then I don't understand the answer; how many decimal places should A have?

Comment: @MathewAlden: If this is in the context of a computer program, then the notion of decimal-place accuracy may be problematic, as (barring special-purpose data structures) a computer's binary nature doesn't necessarily store all decimal values *accurately*. To the extent that the nuances of your chosen language, compiler, system, etc, may come into play for a proper answer, this question might be better-suited to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). On the other hand, if you're looking for a "purely" mathematical solution, then this is certainly a reasonable place to ask.

Comment: Hey @Blue, I appreciate it. And thanks for helping clarify my phrasing. Yes, this is for a computer program. However, I'm using a language that allows me to configure how many decimal places I need - no floating point issues. The only question now, is how many decimal places should I configure it for, hence posting here.